# Why am i getting only one testcase wrong while all other are correct?

Tags: python

**Question**:

> A palindrome is a string that reads the same backward as forward. For
> example, the strings "z", "aaa", "aba", and "abccba" are palindromes,
> but "codeforces" and "ab" are not. You hate palindromes because they
> give you déjà vu.
>
> There is a string s. You must insert exactly one character 'a'
> somewhere in s. If it is possible to create a string that is not a
> palindrome, you should find one example. Otherwise, you should report
> that it is impossible.
>
> For example, suppose s= "cbabc". By inserting an 'a', you can create
> "acbabc", "cababc", "cbaabc", "cbabac", or "cbabca". However "cbaabc"
> is a palindrome, so you must output one of the other options.
>
> **Input** The first line contains a single integer t (1≤t≤104) — the number of test cases.
>
> The only line of each test case contains a string s consisting of
> lowercase English letters.
>
> The total length of all strings does not exceed 3⋅105.
>
> **Output** For each test case, if there is no solution, output "NO".
>
> Otherwise, output "YES" followed by your constructed string of length
> |s|+1 on the next line. If there are multiple solutions, you may print
> any.
>
> You can print each letter of "YES" and "NO" in any case (upper or
> lower).

**Example
input**
6
cbabc
ab
zza
ba
a
nutforajaroftuna

**output**
YES
cbabac
YES
aab
YES
zaza
YES
baa
NO
YES
nutforajarofatuna

**My solution:**

```
n=int(input())
for i in range (0,n):
    x=input().split()
    l=len(x)
    for j in range (0,l):
        
        x.insert(j,"a")
        if x == x[::-1]:
            print("NO")
            del x[j]
            
        else:
            z=''.join(map(str,x))
            print("YES")
            print(z)
            del x[j]
            continue
```

I ran the above given example. All testcases are correct except "zza" in which case i am getting "azza" whereas I should be getting "zaza". The code is telling me that it's NOT a palindrome I dont know why.

Please help.

Comment: `str.split` is not the correct function to turn a string into a list of its characters.

Comment: The problem is that if you DO find a palindrome, you don't delete that letter before you loop again.  You need to delete the letter in both halves of the `if`.  Alternative, you can make a copy of the list each time and manipulate that.

Comment: @TimRoberts but i am deleting with del x[j]

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What should i use then? split adds ' ' but does the work i think.

Comment: `'hello'.split()` produces `['hello']`. `list('hello')` produces `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`. Whenever you're not absolutely sure what you're working with, add a line to print it out so you can see.

Comment: @glorytothe12suns You are deleting in the `else` clause.  You are not deleting in the `if`, if the first insertion happens to result in a palindrome, as would be the case with "zza".

Comment: @TimRoberts Wow good catch! I corrected it but it still returns "azza" for "zza". Help?

Comment: You should `print(x)` after you do the insert.  I think the results will surprise you.  Because you used `split`, you are not producing `['a','z','z','a']`, you are producing `['a','zza']`.  So your comparison of `if x == x[::-1]` always fails.  By sheer accident, the only case that is NOT solved in the first iteration is 'zza'.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you have overcomplicated this problem. Why not try

```
def func(word):
    outcomes = []
    word = [char for char in word]
    for i in range(len(word) + 1):
        word.insert(i, "a")
        if word != word[::-1]:
            outcomes.append("".join(word))
        word.pop(i)

    return list(set(outcomes))


print(func('abba'))
```

It seems a lot simpler. The `list(set(outcomes))` is just a dirty trick to remove all duplicates

Comment: I have not studied sets yet. Can you help me just figure out what exactly is wrong in my code as only one testcase is incorrect everytime i run it everything else is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the results you seek using roughly the same philosophy.  One key is that you can't print "no" until you have tried every location, and you need to stop checking when you get a "yes".

```
#n=int(input())
inp = ['cbabc', 'ab', 'zza', 'ba', 'nutforajarofatuna']
n = len(inp)
for i in range(n):
    x=list(inp[i])
    l=len(x)
    found = False
    for j in range(l):
        x.insert(j,"a")
        if x != x[::-1]:
            z=''.join(map(str,x))
            print("YES")
            print(z)
            found = True
        del x[j]
        if found: 
            break
    if not found:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: Amazing use of True operator. I learnt a lot from this. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a flag.  It's a very, very common concept in cases like this.

Comment: well the time limit got exceeded anyways so i will have to try another approach.